# Angular starting errors in package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, raspbian

Shortform:

> While using 'Angular' for the first time I run in an Error telling me that tsc hasn't been found (package.json at the end).

Detail:

> I am new to Angular and while I started an example from a book with
>   `npm start` I run in an Error with my package.json file. [tsc: not found Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzrbm.png)

```
sh: 1: tsc: not found

npm ERR! blog-app@1.0.0 start: `tsc && npm run copy:html && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run html:watch" "live-server" `
npm ERR! Exit status 127
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the blog-app@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the blog-app package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     tsc && npm run copy:html && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run html:watch" "live-server"
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls blog-app
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Linux 4.14.62-v7+
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! cwd /home/pi/webpages/3914_Zusatzmaterialien/kickstart/hello-angular
npm ERR! node -v v8.11.1
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pi/webpages/3914_Zusatzmaterialien/kickstart/hello-angular/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

> I was supposed to run `npm install` in the directory of that distribution causing the follow error:

```
(node:1635) [DEP0022] DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.
npm WARN package.json blog-app@1.0.0 No README data
npm WARN deprecated typings@1.0.4: Typings is deprecated in favor of NPM @types -- see README for more information
npm ERR! Error: Method Not Allowed
npm ERR!     at errorResponse (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache/add-named.js:260:10)
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/cache/add-named.js:203:12
npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:167:7)
npm ERR!     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:135:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 4.14.62-v7+
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/pi/webpages/angulartry
npm ERR! node -v v8.11.1
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
npm ERR! code E405
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pi/webpages/angulartry/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

> i removed it multiple times and reinstalled it with `npm install -g typescript`.
>
> `npm install && npm start` causes the following error

```
(node:1814) [DEP0022] DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.
npm WARN package.json blog-app@1.0.0 No README data
npm WARN deprecated typings@1.0.4: Typings is deprecated in favor of NPM @types -- see README for more information
npm ERR! Error: Method Not Allowed
npm ERR!     at errorResponse (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache/add-named.js:260:10)
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/cache/add-named.js:203:12
npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:167:7)
npm ERR!     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:135:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 4.14.62-v7+
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/pi/webpages/3914_Zusatzmaterialien/kickstart/hello-angular
npm ERR! node -v v8.11.1
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
npm ERR! code E405
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pi/webpages/3914_Zusatzmaterialien/kickstart/hello-angular/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

> If I remove `tsc &&` from line 11 
>   `"start": "tsc && npm run copy:html
>   && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run html:watch\"
>   \"live-server\" ",` , I run in the following error `sh: 1:
>   copyfiles: not found`.

About the System:

> The System is running on a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian using npm version `npm: '1.4.21'`. 
>   My Typescript Version seems to be 2.2.1. If it matters, I control the System from a Putty.

The package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "blog-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Blog Applikation",
  "watch": {
    "copy:html": "./app/**/*.html"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "tsc": "./node_modules/.bin/tsc",
    "tsc:w": "./node_modules/.bin/tsc --watch",
    "start": "tsc && npm run copy:html && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run html:watch\" \"live-server\" ",
    "html:watch": "onchange \"./app/**/*.html\" -v -- npm run copy:html",
    "copy:html": "copyfiles -u 1 ./app/**/*.html dist"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": ">=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": ">=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": ">=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": ">=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": ">=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": ">=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": ">=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.4",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "concurrently": "2.2.0",
    "copyfiles": "1.0.0",
    "http-server": "0.9.0",
    "live-server": "1.1.0",
    "lodash": "4.11.1",
    "npm-watch": "0.1.6",
    "onchange": "3.0.2",
    "rimraf": "2.5.2",
    "tslint": "3.7.4",
    "typescript": "2.2.0",
    "typings": "1.0.4"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `typescript` did not be installed successfully. You can try :

```
npm install -g typescript
```

And then

```
npm install && npm start
```

Comment: This has already been tried, also after removing everything that has something to do with typescript. Right now it gives me the directories of typescript.

Comment: while the second one ends in an error, I add to the question.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to generate project using angular cli and check its package.json file, it looks a bit different than yours